# Android executes codes faster than PC

Tags: android, java

The same code for Android (1Ghz Snapdragon) executes 2 time faster, than on my PC (in desktop application) with 3.3 Ghz Core 2 Duo (class from PC was copied to Android project). Tested with Win7 and Debian. Time mesured by System.currentTimeMillis() for only one (main) calculating method. Why it's happend and what can I do to fix it?

UPD1. First application running on real android device, second - in JRE

UPD2. In that part of applications, that I try to compare, used only simple math and operations with BigDecimal (multiply, sqrt, divide and so on). Idea - calculate pi by [gauss-legendre algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_algorithm)

Comment: hmm i understand you are talking about some plain java code.!! what code did you execute on android/pc. interesting observation though.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to be more specific about what you're doing to monitor this.  There are a large number of factors at play that could influence this. If you're running on the emulator, forget it -- it's incredibly slow, there's really no comparison there.  However, I get the feeling you're talking about one application running in the JVM as a standard Java application and another application running on Dalvik, but there, you really can't compare either.  Different frameworks have different libraries and different calls that are implemented in different ways.  Not to mention Dalvik is optimized differently than the standard JVM and so on.

You'll need to give us more information in order for us to attempt to give you an explanation, but I suspect you're trying to compare two things that really can't be compared.

Answer (score 0):

I think because the Android device has a different processor architecture than your PC, so the CPU on your PC needs to emulate the Android, so it would do much more processing.

Comment: i am assuming by running on PC, you mean the emulator

Comment: code was written like desktop application. When I start emulator, it executes 5 times slower =D

Comment: you mean the android virtual device that come with the SDK right? then yes, basically, the processor on your PC will "translate" your code into a language that would run the exact same way as your android device, so it would use more processing power as your PC speak a different language as your android device.

Comment: And from the begining: when I try to compare results, I dont use any virtual devices, android phone and application for it and application for pc jre, but I used one class in both applications